# Glue application.conf in gradle project

Tags: java, scala, akka, akka-persistence

I´m doing some practical examples with Akka. Everything fine so far. But now that I start looking Akka persistence, in all blogs that I read they said that I need to configure the persistence in the application.conf

```
akka {
  persistence {
    journal.plugin = "inmemory-journal"
    snapshot-store.plugin = "inmemory-snapshot-store"
  }
}
```

My project it´s just a gradle project. And I don't understand how to glue this config file with my test cases that need to use the in memory persistence.

Someone can point me in the right direction about how to glue the config with my example execution.

Here you can see the code

https://github.com/politrons/Akka/tree/master/src/main/scala/persistence

When I run my object App I receive this error

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: default journal plugin is not configured, see 'reference.conf'
```